# How do we calculate the push-forward measure.

Tags: measure-theory, differential-topology

Consider the map $\varphi:S^1\times \mathbb (0, \infty)\to \mathbb R^2$ which takes $(p, t)$ to $tp$.
(Here $S^1$ is thought of as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Thus writing $tp$ means scaling $p$ by $t$.)

> **Question.** Equipping $S^1\times (0, \infty)$ with the product of the respective Lebesgue measures, I want to calculate what is the push-forward of this measure under $\varphi$.

This is a basic question about measures but the only way I could think of doing this is by computing the pull-back of the volume form on $\mathbb R^2$ under $\varphi$, which is doable by a simple derivatives calculation.

Comment: What's the definition of muliplication between an element of $S^1$ and an element of $(0,\infty)$?  Are you identifying $S^1$ with the interval $[0,1)$?

Comment: @Adam I have edited to explain the the meaning.